# Putty manual session and Plink session behave differently

Tags: bash, putty, plink

HI I'm connecting to a remote Linux server using putty from a win PC and executing certain commands there. I wish to automate the tasks using plink as follows:

`plink serveradress -l userid -pwd pass -batch "ls;cmd1"`

If I perform the commands "ls;cmd1;cmd2" manually through putty/plink its works fine. However, if I do the same thorugh cmd.ext and teh above plink command , i get "bash cmd1 not found". However, ls command works fine.

Why does this happen? PS: cmd1 is not a inbuilt linux command. Its created specifically for the server I suppose.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

When bash complains about 'command not found' it means that the command `cmd1` cannot be found in `$PATH`. So either you must make sure that the path for `cmd1` is always in `$PATH`, or you must specify the full pathname for `cmd1`:

```
plink serveradress -l userid -pwd pass -batch "ls;/where/you/can/find/cmd1"
```

You can find that full pathname with `which cmd1` in your interactive shell (the one via putty).

You can set the PATH in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, that is the .bashrc or .profile in your home directory.

You can check the PATH with `echo $PATH` in your putty session or with `plink serveradress -l userid -pwd pass -batch 'echo $PATH'` (note the single quotes). If you do both, you should see a difference.

Comment: I donot know the path to the scripts like bashrc, etc that are run during my login_session = on. Is there any way I can start a "LOGIN" type session through plink..so I automatically run those scripts and that cmd1 works even though I dont know the path. Alternative ly is there any way that i can know all the paths to the scripts that are run during my login_session=on. PS - none of these are in my home dir

Comment: Added some additional info to the answer; check if that's enough for you.

Comment: Fantastic. Except one, all my commands now work in non interactive session! The thing about the one cmd which does not work is that the cmd is set in a second .sh which is source-d from a main .sh file.Also, in the .I could manually construct the actual .sh to be sourced path from the main .sh file..but I wont prefer this option as this path is dynamic -Its changes regularly :/ . Also, does such in-directing sourc-ing of a .sh file from another main .sh/alias-ing  problematic in non interactive/no-login sessions by any chance?